# Handling Nil In Ruby

Tags: ruby

In .Net there is one option for null values like `a = a ?? "" + "some string value"`

This means if a is null take a as "" this. I want to know is there any thing like this in ruby.

Comment: Can you explain this code? `a = a ?? "" + "some string value"`. This is confusing.. with what you said by _This means if a is null take a as ""_.

Comment: if a = null , then when i do concatenation it will throw an error. To prevent the error we have to handle it . so if you use ?? this operator in .Net you can assign a default value like a ?? "" or  a ?? "default string" anything you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prepend/append it to a string, best thing to do is:

```
a.to_s + "some string value"
```

This will automatically handle even the `nil` values.

```
a = nil
a.to_s
# => ""
```

Answer (score 6):

In Ruby, you can do:

```
a ||= ''
```

this means that if `a` is `nil` or `false`, empty string would be assigned to it. Note that this is an expression that returns eventual value of `a`.

Comment: Yes, this is what we have in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, if an object could be converted to a String, we can do like
`"#{nil} some string value"`

Here, it takes the `nil`(or some value) as string.

Comment: That's way better. This is how I'd do it.